# Login por roles de sesion

Tags: php, pdo, session, users-roles

Buenas tardes,noches, estoy realizando un login por roles de sesión y con dos me funciona perfectamente, tal que así:

user.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
    if($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 0){

    }else{
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }

     }else{
     header("Location: index.php");
     }     
?>
```

admin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
    if($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 1){

    }else{
        header("Location: user.php");
    }
}else{
     header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Ahora quiero añadir un nuevo rol pero no consigo hacer que funcione no me lo detecta una de las formas que intente fue de la siguiente manera pero siempre me manda a la pagina del rol user en admin y el nuevo rol no redirecciona bien:

user.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
    if($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 0){

header("Location: user.php");
    }   
}
?>
```

admin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
    if($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 1){

header("Location: admin.php");
    }   
}
?>
```

jefe.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
    if($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 2){

header("Location: jefe.php");
    }   
}
?>
```

Añado de donde obtengo los datos

```
<?php

include "../controlador/usuariosControlador.php";

if(isset($_POST["usuario"]) || isset($_POST["pass"])){
if(trim($_POST["usuario"]) == "" || trim($_POST["pass"]) == ""){
    echo "false";
}else{
    $usuariosCon = new usuariosControlador();
    $usuario = $usuariosCon->validar($_POST["usuario"],$_POST["pass"]);

    if(count($usuario) > 0){

        session_start();
        $_SESSION["id"] = $usuario["id"];
        $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario["usuario"];
        $_SESSION["privilegio"] = $usuario["privilegio"];
        echo "true";

         }else{
            echo "false";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "false";
}


?>
```

Comment: Fijate si haciendo session_destroy(); funciona, ya que puede ser que están quedando los valores guardados y por lo tanto no toma los nuevos

Comment: si, todos tienen un enlace debajo que pone cerrar sesion que redirige a un php que contiene esto:

<?php

    session_start();
    session_destroy();

    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";

?>

Comment: a) - Pondrías el código completo ? 
b) - No entiendo la lógica de los primeros 2 bloques de código que pegaste; que relación tiene con lo que intentas hacer abajo?

Comment: Esta completo, los dos primeros bloques son dos archivos php que le indica si eres 0 eres usuario normal por tanto accedes a user.php y si eres 1 eres admin por lo tanto accedes a admin.php ahora necesito añadir un tercer rol el cual no consigo hacer que funcione.
Tambien es que si no eres user hace un else que entonces si no eres 0 seras 1 entonces eres admin.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que dices en los comentarios, y siguiendo tu código de referencia que Funciona, el archivo jefe.php debería ser mas o menos así:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"]))
    {
        if($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 2)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: admin.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }     
?>
```

Comment: intenta entrar en admin.php :S los demas si entran correctamente a su sitio pero este no redirige a jefe.php siempre intenta entrar en admin.php

Comment: Eso quiere decir que en  if($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 2) no está dando TRUE... comprueba que sea 2

Comment: como puedo comprobarlo?

Comment: echo $_SESSION["privilegio"]

Comment: user da 0 que es el que debe de dar, admin da 1 pero no puedo ver el de jefe porque como me intenta mandar a admin.php no imprime nada unicamente: La página no está redirigiendo adecuadamente, vamos como si no existiera

Comment: hazlo fuera del if pues... o sacale la redireccion al else

Comment: session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
  if($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 0)
header ("Location: user.php") asi por ejemplo

Comment: no, algo así
 if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"]))
 { 
  echo $_SESSION["privilegio"]
 }

Comment: Puse esto en los 3 archivos:  <?php
if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])) { echo $_SESSION["privilegio"]; }
?>
<p>user<p>
<a href='cerrarsesion.php'>cerrar session</a>

Y entran todos como admin, sus muertos loco xD!

Comment: Entonces lo que no está funcionando es el cerrar sesion

Comment: o la consulta a la base o de donde sea que traes el valor de privilegio

Comment: pero es muy raro porque con dos roles funciona perfectamente es al meter un tercer rol

Comment: Añadi de donde obtengo los datos al final del post